# Adding GzipCompressor Message handler causes HttpContext.Current to be null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I understand if I run a separate thread I lose HttpContext population... not sure if that's what is happening here.  I set up my Application_Start as follows:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, new ServerCompressionHandler(new GZipCompressor(), new DeflateCompressor()));
    }
```

In order to both decompress and compress message bodies as they are received and sent from the server.

However, after doing this and sending a gzipCompressed body to my server I get the data in an uncompressed format as expected, however HttpContext.Current is null now.  This is important information as I need IP Address and other information contained within the HttpContext Class.

I tried using GzipStream request filtering to no avail.  I feel like there is a really obvious and easy solution I am missing.  for reference my endpoint looks as follows (very generically)
Edit: to show class inheritance

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{    
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/endpoint")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] RequstDataObject request)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What `class` is your `public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] RequstDataObject request)` method in? Don't you have access to `HttpContext` via inheritance?

Comment: `catch (Exception ex)`  <-- Don't do this. Catch more specific exceptions, and don't return HTTP 400 for server-side errors...

Comment: @Dai the class is a Controller which inherits ApiController.  I have access to HttpContext, however the values are lost when the MessageHandler is added...  If I set a breakpoint in Application_BeginRequest, the HttpContext is populated, then when it gets to the API endpoint everything in HttpContext is null.  If I remove the Message handler from the Application Start this problem does not exist, but then I don't have GzipCompression

Comment: @Dai my assumption is the GzipCompressor is set up to run the Endpoint on a separate thread which is which the HttpContext is no longer populated

Comment: Solution Found at https://github.com/azzlack/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.MessageHandlers.Compression/issues/45   "Suchiman commented on Mar 27, 2019" fixed the problem